# Como criar e escrever arquivo txt em java?

Tags: java

Gostaria de saber como criar e escrever em arquivo txt. O objetivo é escrever em padrão CSV, tentei com BufferedWriter e não deu certo...

```
import java.io.*;

public class PersistenciaComArquivoDeString
{

    public void salvaPessoas(ListaComArray<Pessoa> lista)
    {
        try
        {
            BufferedWriter saida = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("pessoa.txt"));
            Pessoa aux ;
            for(int i=0 ; i<lista.tamanho() ; i++)
            {
                aux = lista.get(i);
                saida.write(aux.getNome());
                saida.newLine();
                saida.write(aux.getEndereco());
                saida.newLine();
                // saida.write(String.valueOf(aux.getIdade()));
                // saida.newLine();
                
                saida.close();
                
            }
            
        }        
        catch(IOException e)
        {
        }
    }

}
```

Provavelmente o problema está sendo na criação do arquivo, alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: O `close` está dentro do `for`, então na primeira iteração já fechará o arquivo. Além disso, não deveria ter vírgula entre as informações, em vez de `newLine`?

Answer (score 2):

No pacote java.io temos tudo que precisamos para trabalhar com leitura e escrita de arquivos.

Exemplo 01 de escrita de arquivo:

```
public class TesteEscritaDeArquivo_1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        //Fluxo de saida de um arquivo
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("file1.txt"); // nome do arquivo que será escrito
        Writer wr = new OutputStreamWriter(os); // criação de um escritor
        BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(wr); // adiciono a um escritor de buffer
        
        br.write("Vamos escrever nesse novo arquivo em Java! que legal hahaha!!!");
        br.newLine();
        br.newLine();
        br.write("Vamos escrever outra linha aqui embaixo hahaha!!!");
        br.close();
    }
}
```

Os passos foram:

1: instanciamos nosso arquivo de dados através do **FileOutputStream**

2: instanciamos nosso escritor que recebe em seu construtor a referencia do **OutputStream**

3: Instanciamos nosso **Buffer** que será capaz de escrever no arquivo

4: os comportamentos são descritos no próprio nome do método, mas chamo a atenção para que sempre é preciso fechar o recurso que abrimos e fazemos isso com o **close();**

As próximas formas são simples e mais comuns de serem vistas no java.

```
public class TesteEscritaDeArquivo_2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("file2"));
        
        br.write("Vamos escrever nesse novo arquivo em Java! que legal hahaha!!!");
        br.newLine();
        br.newLine();
        br.write("Vamos escrever outra linha aqui embaixo hahaha!!!");
        br.close();
    }
}
```

Nessa implementação utilizamos a classe **BufferedWriter** que está no **java** desde a versão 1.1 para escrever o arquivo.

no seu construtor passamos diretamente o **FileWriter**, você está utilizando essa opção como não mostrou os demais detalhes sobre sua implementação como por exemplo outros comportamentos classes fica complicado.

```
public class TesteEscritaDeArquivo_3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream("file3.txt");
        
        ps.print("Vamos escrever nesse novo arquivo em Java! que legal hahaha!!!");
        ps.println();
        ps.println();
        ps.print("Vamos escrever outra linha aqui embaixo hahaha!!!");
        ps.close();
    }
}
```

Nesse caso utilizamos o PrintStream que surgiu no java 1.5 e nesse caso passamos diretamente o nome do arquivo em seu construtor.

```
public class TesteEscritaDeArquivo_4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        PrintWriter ps = new PrintWriter("file3.txt");
        
        ps.print("Vamos escrever nesse novo arquivo em Java! que legal hahaha!!!");
        ps.println();
        ps.println();
        ps.print("Vamos escrever outra linha aqui embaixo hahaha!!!!!!!!");
        ps.close();
    }
}
```

Nesse caso utilizamos a classe PrintWriter.

Ainda para leitura de arquivos temos diversas opções também,você pode dentre outros utilizar a classe Scanner passando o arquivo dentro do construtor.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("contas.csv"));
```

As classes de escritas e leitura de arquivos no java tem exceções do tipo **Checked** ou seja você é obrigado a tratá-las de alguma forma, eu coloquei essas exceções no main apenas como teste, em um cenário real seria mais indicado colocar dentro do comportamento da classe que está o implementando.

Aproveite ao máximo os recursos de **java.io** vale a pena.